# Are there any tables that I can get all Oracle supported system privileges and object privileges?

Tags: oracle, permissions, role

Are there any tables that I can get all Oracle supported system privileges and object privileges? I know there is a view called `all_sys_privs` in Oracle. But I can't find more information about it.

Thanks.

Comment: DBA_SYS_PRIVS describes system privileges granted to users and roles. What I need is all the privileges names that Oracle support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [`SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5177.htm#REFRN29508)?

Comment: Yes, it's this view. How about all object privileges?

Comment: If you want a list of all possible object privileges, you will have to construct it from [`dba_objects`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_4156.htm#REFRN23146)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query for object privileges by object type.

```
SELECT o.object_type, t.privilege 
FROM dba_tab_privs t
JOIN dba_objects   o
  ON t.owner = o.owner
 AND t.table_name = o.object_name
GROUP BY o.object_type, t.PRIVILEGE
ORDER BY o.object_type, t.PRIVILEGE
;
```

The following takes into account privilege types that exist in table_privilege_map but not in the existing database objects.

```
SELECT o.object_type, m.name AS privilege 
FROM table_privilege_map m
LEFT OUTER JOIN (dba_tab_privs t
      JOIN dba_objects   o
        ON t.owner = o.owner
       AND t.table_name = o.object_name)
  ON m.NAME = t.PRIVILEGE
GROUP BY o.object_type, m.NAME
ORDER BY o.object_type, m.name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into sys.table_privilege_map (at-least 11g onwards, might exist before but I have no way to check) for a listing of possible object privileges, be warned not all apply to all object types.